# Can I install DD-WRT firmware on my Virgin SOHO router Hub 3.0 VMDG505?

Tags: networking, router

I have a Virgin SOHO router Hub 3.0 VMDG505 (ARRISGro_88:fb:3) provided by my ISP (Virgin) here in the UK.
The web interface doesn't allow you to do much, so I thought I may install some good routing Web interface like DD-WRT.

I wonder if this is possible, if it's recommended and if it would void my warranty.

I'd like to do it to play with the settings as I'm a networking student.

Or maybe it's easier for me to get a modem and router and switch and do my own tests with that here at home.

Any recommendations much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *might* be possible but a) they don't allow it & b) it would no longer connect. They're locked to your account by soft/firmware inside. Contractually, few UK ISPs allow you to use your own router.

Simplest is to drop them to pure modem mode & just put a new router behind it. You lose the WiFi in doing that so you have to provide your own.
Another thing you gain from that is that if ever you need an engineer, locally or remotely, it will still interact properly with their equipment.

[Virgin Community - variations on a theme of dropping your hub to modem mode](https://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Networking-and-WiFi/Advice-on-how-to-put-Hub-5-into-Modem-mode-amp-what-router-to/td-p/4993448)

I've been doing this since I first swapped to Virgin from BT 15 years ago or more.

Comment: Great answer.   Thanks!